# Usage de l'adjectif "opulent"

Tags: vocabulaire, usage

Je souhaiterais savoir si l'adjectif opulent peut être utilisé dans ce cas :

> Ce fut villa opulente que l'on nous présenta en premier.

Il me semblait que cet adjectif ne s'employait que pour désigner une personne...

Peut-il être utilisé pour un objet ou un lieu ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rien n'interdit de qualifier une villa d'opulente en revanche, un article est attendu devant *villa* et le présent peut remplacer le passé simple :

> C'est **une villa opulente** que l'on nous présenta en premier.

J'utiliserais cependant plutôt ***somptueuse*** ou ***luxueuse*** qu'*opulente*.

S'il faut vraiment utiliser le passé simple et s'aventurer dans des effets de style, l'article peut être omis et on peut tenter :

> Ce fut villa opulente qu'en premier on nous présenta.

Comment: L'article n'est pas obligatoire, même si cela relève du vieux français. C'est comme dans la phrase "Ce fut belle promenade que nous fîmes"

Comment: @Nathan Oui, l'article n'est pas strictement obligatoire et c'est pour ça que j'ai seulement écrit qu'il était **attendu**. Je ne pense pas que Lulucmy souhaite rédiger sa phrase dans un style aussi ampoulé et c'est aussi pour ça que j'ai suggéré de laisser tomber le passé simple, mais je me trompe peut-être.